# Nodemailer not working when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, nodemailer

I am using `nodemailer` to send email in my server using `express`. Everything worked perfectly in the localhost but when I deploy it on Heroku, it does not work anymore, look like it not support `nodemailer` on Heroku (that is what I have researched). This is my code, would you please help me out to deal with it. Thank you so much and have a good day

`This is sending single mail`

```
    exports.send_mail = (req, res, next) => {
      var {subjectTo, mailList, content} = req.body;
      var {attachURL} = req;
    
      var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
        },
      });
    
      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com',
        to: mailList,
        cc: mailList,
        subject: subjectTo,
        text: `${content} \n Attached files: ${attachURL}`,
      };
    
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(400).json({err});
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({message: `Mail sent to ${mailList}`});
        }
      });
    };
```

`This is sending merge mail/multiple mail`

```
exports.merge_mail = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('merge mail begin');
  const mailOptionList = req.body;
  // {mails, mailContent, mailTitle}
  var counter = 0;

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < mailOptionList.length; i++) {
    var mailOptions = {
      from: 'sale.shopeeholic@gmail.com',
      to: mailOptionList[i].mails.join(','),
      cc: mailOptionList[i].mails.join(','),
      subject: mailOptionList[i].mailTitle,
      text: mailOptionList[i].mailContent,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({err, message: `trouble in sending mail at index ${i}`});
      } else {
        console.log(`mail sent to ${JSON.stringify(mailOptionList[i].mails)}`);
        counter++;
      }
    });
    console.log(`mail sent to ${JSON.stringify(mailOptionList[i].mails)}`);
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
  }

  if (counter === mailOptionList.length) {
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'mail sent all'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `process.env.EMAIL` and `process.env.PASSWORD` are undefined. You have to set env variables in Heroku. Here's how:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Have you tried replacing `service: "gmail"` with `host: "smtp.gmail.com"`?

Comment: oh i haven't added host for it yet, but i set port for it, i have researched and look like it is default port for nodemailer on Heroku

Comment: Try this configuration: `host: 'smtp.gmail.com'`, `port: 587`, `secure: false`